# VS 2017 setup project current icon not showing

Tags: c#, setup-project

[image]

Hi,

I hope above picture can explain all about my problem.

I added and selected icon file in Application Folder.

But, next screen is showing only File name. There is no Current icon image.

So I can't click OK button. Last time I did it successfully but I don't know why it doesn't show up now.

Please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: The Icon might not be the correct dimensions or format, something like that.  Check the properties against another icon that does work.

Answer (score -1):

It becames when icon format is not appropriate. Changing format by change extension from ex. ".png" to ".ico" cause this error.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) - [From Review] (add review link)